# How can I make columns in Linq query rows?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table which contains rows like below

```
Month - Agent   - ResolveCount  
1     - John    - 14    
1     - John    - 12           
2     - Smith   - 64              
2     - Smith   - 23
```

### My Model:

```
public int Month { get; set; }
public Agent Agent { get; set; }
public int ResolveCount { get; set; }
```

### My Linq Query

```
   List<ResolveMonthlyAgentReport> _result =
        (from t in ConversationCollection.AsQueryable<Conversation>().AsEnumerable()
        where t.CompanyId == _companyId && t.CreateDate.Year == _year && t.ResolvedDate != null && t.ResolvedAgentId != null
            group t by new { t.CreateDate.Month, t.ResolvedAgentId }
            into grp
            orderby grp.Key.Month
            select new ResolveMonthlyAgentReport
            {
            Agent = _agentList.Where(p => p.AgentId.ToString() == grp.Key.ResolvedAgentId).FirstOrDefault(),
            Month = grp.Key.Month,
            ResolveCount = grp.Count(t => t.ResolvedAgentId == grp.Key.ResolvedAgentId) 
            })
        .Where(p => p.Agent != null)
        .ToList();
```

### Result:

```
Month - Agent   - ResolveCount  
1     - John    - 14    
1     - John    - 12           
2     - Smith   - 64              
2     - Smith   - 23
```

.
.

### This is the result I Want:

```
Agent    - 1.month - 2.month - x.month
John     - 14      - 12
Smith    - 64      - 23
```

How should my linq query be?

Comment: so `agent`,`1.month`,`2.month` are static columns? or if you have `x` value  result would be `x.month`?

Comment: x.month no static..

Comment: You will need pivot table query